# How to properly track keys with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm doing a web calculator, I need to track when when the user type a number key, but this calculator also has two input type="number" to define the range that the numbers will be generated.

```js
let from = document.querySelector("#from")
let to = document.querySelector("#to")
let regex = /[\d]/
from.addEventListener("focus", () => {
  console.log('focus')
});

document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  if (evt.key.match(regex)) {
    alert(evt.key);
  } else if (evt.key == 'Enter') {
    alert(evt.key)
  };
};
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <span>Range: from </span>
  <input type="number" id="from" value="0">
  <span>to</span>
  <input type="number" id="to" value="100">
</div>
```

How I can stop tracking the keys only when the user is typing on the input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to check if document.activeElement is equals to the element that you want to check.

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  if (from === document.activeElement) {
    console.log("jaisokdjhaslkdhjsa")
  } else {
    if (evt.key.match(regex)) {
      alert(evt.key);
    } else if (evt.key == 'Enter') {
      alert(evt.key)
    };
  } 
};
```